# Are variables declared in loops visible to rest of the code?

Tags: c++, scope, variable-declaration

I was reading this book and it said :
**Variables declared in a scope aren't visible outside it.**

It also said :
**Scopes are declared by 2 curly braces - like a block of code.**

So, if I had a situation like this :

```
for(_statement1_)
{
  int var;
  /*code*/
}
cout << var << " number of rockets left.\n";
```

***Would the value printed be the same as the value of the `var` declared in the loop?***

Thank you

Comment: It would be a compiler error. `var` is not declared in the outer scope.

Comment: Alright. So if you could write it as an answer, I'll declare the question as answered.

Comment: I'll pass. This is too trivial to be answered, and I am sure there are duplicates.

Comment: You could have just tried out instead of asking a question.

Comment: @Csq I'm away from my PC

Comment: @AnitejBanerjee: But clearly you are somehow connected to the internet. Try this: https://ideone.com/  See: https://ideone.com/HSwjwU

Comment: @Csq Gee! Thanks :)
Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your book says, the variable is scoped inside the loop's block, and isn't visible outside it.

Your code won't compile unless there is a different variable `var` outside the loop's scope. If there is, then the final statement would use that, not the one in the loop which is now out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not use that variable outside the loop. var is visible only inside the loop.

Comment: You meant to write `can't`, right?

Comment: yes, typing mistake initially!!

Answer (score 0):

It will be a compiler error since the scope of var limited inside for loop only.